# error ; qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display while running gnuplot

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, qt, gnuplot

[image]I have tried many solutions but I am not able to start gnuplot or any program that needs display using qt. I am using ubuntu extension in windows WSL.